# Use wkwebview back reload

Tags: ios, wkwebview

I am using WKWebview，I want that when I click the back button, it refresh the page rather than reading the page cache.

```
if (self.webView.canGoBack) {
    [self.webView goBack];
    [self.webView reload];
}
```

But, when you return to certain pages these are loaded twice and can't return to the first page.

Do not know to have people meet the same requirements and how to solve? The premise is not use UIWebview.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing the same issue. After removing the reload method, it was working correctly.

```
if ([self.wkWebView canGoBack]) {
    [self.wkWebView goBack];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var backNavigation: WKNavigation?

func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
    if backNavigation?.isEqual(navigation) ?? false {
        webView.reload()
        backNavigation = nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in my page's js file, I add this and it worked.

```
    var solveLoadingProblem = function () {
            window.addEventListener("popstate", function (e) {
                location.reload(true);
            });
    };
solveLoadingProble();
```